# Can we run angular without build step

Tags: angular

Can we run angular without build step?

By just using CDN. without angular cli.

And have external dependencies of libraries as CDN.

Comment: your CDN should be only .html and .js (the bundles that create Angular)

Answer (score 2):

No. Angular apps are written in Typescript, and the "build step" compiles the Typescript to JavaScript.

Web browsers run JavaScript, not Typescript.
So the "build step" is required.